# append node using current or current->next

Tags: c, linked-list

Only difference is current is swapped to current->next. I figure they would both work the same but apparently not. Does it confuse it with the local(current) instead of head?

Why doesn't appendNodeTailCurrent work, but when I use (appendNodeTailNext) current->next it works?

```
void appendNodeTailNext(NODE** head, int data) {
    NODE* current = *head;
    NODE* node = { 0 };
    node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (current == NULL) {
        *head = node;
        return;
    }

    while (current->next!= NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = node;
}

void appendNodeTailCurrent(NODE** head, int data) {
    NODE* current = *head;
    NODE* node = { 0 };
    node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (current == NULL) {
        *head = node;
        return;
    }

    while (current!= NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current = node;
}
```

Comment: "I figure they would both work the same". Why would you think changing that part of the code would have no effect? The first one finds the last node in the existing list and chains the new node to it. The second one finds the last node and then just sets a **local variable** with a pointer to that node.

Comment: In your second function, what points to the new node when you are done? (i.e. does the previous `node->next` in the list point to it? or is that pointer to it not set?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `*head` isn't `NULL`, the second version changes neither `*head` nor any part of any node of the list. It therefore doesn't change the list. It only changes `current`, a variable that ceases to exist once the function exits.

---

For example, say there are already four nodes in the list.

First version:

1. `current` is set to the first node.
2. `next` of the first node is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
3. `current` is set to the second node.
4. `next` of the second node is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
5. `current` is set to the third node.
6. `next` of the third node is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
7. `current` is set to the fourth node.
8. `next` of the fourth node is `NULL`, so the loop exits.
9. `next` of the fourth node is set to the new node.

We have changed a node (in the final step).

Second version:

1. `current` is set to the first node.
2. `current` is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
3. `current` is set to the second node.
4. `current` is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
5. `current` is set to the third node.
6. `current` is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
7. `current` is set to the fourth node.
8. `current` is not `NULL`, so the loop is entered.
9. `current` is set to `NULL`.
10. `current` is not `NULL`, so the loop exits.
11. `current` is set to the new node.

We haven't changed `*head` or a node.

---

There is a way of making the second approach work: By adding a layer of indirection.

```
void appendNodeTailCurrent(NODE** head, int data) {
    NODE** ptr_to_ptr = head;
    NODE* node = { 0 };
    node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (*ptr_to_ptr == NULL) {
        *head = node;
        return;
    }

    while (*ptr_to_ptr!= NULL) {
        ptr_to_ptr = &( (*ptr_to_ptr)->next );
    }

    *ptr_to_ptr = node;
}
```

The above simplifies to the following:

```
void appendNodeTailCurrent(NODE** ptr_to_ptr, int data) {
    while (*ptr_to_ptr != NULL) {
        ptr_to_ptr = &( (*ptr_to_ptr)->next );
    }

    *ptr_to_ptr = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    (*ptr_to_ptr)->data = data;
    (*ptr_to_ptr)->next = NULL;
}
```

You could say the first version you posted finds the node to change, while this version finds the pointer to change. In the first version you posted, the head needed to be treated specially because it wasn't a node. But since the head is a pointer, we don't need to treat it specially in this version.

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: No need for the extra parenthesis with `&( (*ptr_to_ptr)->next);`. The set around the dereferenced pointer will do, `&(*ptr_to_ptr)->next;`.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, Thanks, but I'll leave them in place assuming the OP doesn't know the relative precedence of `&` and `->`. I'm used to unary operators having a higher precedence than binary ones, and I'm sure I'm not the only one!

Comment: @David C. Rankin, ...But it makes sense cause I know I have to use `(*ptr_to_ptr)->next` rather than `*ptr_to_ptr->next`, and one would expect the referencing (`&`) and dereferencing (`*`) operators to have the same precedence.

Comment: It's good to emphasize the point. The larger issue for OP to grasp is by iterating with both the address of the pointer and pointer to node, you can assign/replace the node at that address and the previous->next pointer still points to that correct address.